# The blank page between last chapter and list of symbols

Tags: chapters, input, blank-page, baseline

I have problem with blank page but the answers I've found here didn't work. I have found two (unwanted) ways how to get rid of the page (under the code):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[IL2]{fontenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{a4wide}

\newcommand{\vsg}{\\[0.4cm]}
\newcommand{\sg}{\\[0.6cm]} 

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{czech}
\chapter{Conclusion}
\input{./chapters/conclus.tex}
%
% HERE IS THE BLANK PAGE
%
\chapter*{List of used symbols}
\input{./chapters/symbols.tex}
\end{document}
```

1) If I use

```
\chapter{List of used symbols}
```

without a star, everything is ok, but I dont want to have Chapter "List of symbols" and I have to use documentclass report

2) When I remove

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.4}
```

or use the value 1.3 it is ok, but my work is already formated for 1.4.
I suppose there is enough space to avoid adding blank page. Please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: does the blank page have an even number?  (chapter pages, whether or not the starred version of `\chapter` is used, by default begin on a right-hand page, which has an odd number.  if your blank page has an odd number, then something is very strange.  unfortunately, i can't test your example to see what happens.)

Comment: It has number 4...yes it has an even number

Comment: I have found the problem. The list of symbols was a bigger table, that seemed to fit on the page but didn't. Removing two rows caused disappearance of the blank page.

I don't know why, but it worked!
Thank you for the cooperation and all related topics on this forum! :-)

Comment: @Karel  Since you have found a solution to your question, please consider posting it as an answer and then accepting it.  It'll make it easier for others who encounter the same problem to find the solution.